# Rails Migration & ruby protected keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I just received advice from someone that I should not use ruby keywords as table column names in my db. One of my tables had a column called 'public'.

I ran a migration to rename the column to 'disclose' and changed the form and show in the views to use the new name. I also changed the permitted param in the controller.

However, when i try to use the form, it gives an error saying that public cannot be blank (although there is no use of that attribute in my code anymore). I then found an answer on SO which said to make a column called public. So i added a new column with that name and gave it a default false attribute, although it isn't used anywhere.

I still get an error saying that public can't be blank when i try to create a new record of that class.

I then tried to rollback the migrations to go back to the start before I tried to make this change and I'm getting error saying that rollback won't work where the remove column is given a type.

Does anyone know how to untangle this mess. Im happy to just get back to using a ruby keyword as a column name in my table. It's better than this mess.

Thank you

Comment: could you post your model file? `public can't be blank` refers to a validation, not a migration issue

Comment: That's what I forgot to change. My search on the word didn't find it. Thank you